# "pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

upd2:Вот что пишет после ввода в PATH
[image: Изменения после ввода в PATH2]
[image: Изменения после ввода в PATH1]
upd:Изменил путь к pyinstaller, попробовал использовать. Всё та же проблема
[image: Изменил путь к pyinstaller, попробовал использовать. Всё та же проблема]
Использую pyinstaller, он выдает "pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
В папке с скриптами pyinstaller установлен
[image: Использую pyinstaller, он выдает "pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.]

[image: В папке с скриптами pyinstaller установлен]

Я не понимаю в чем проблема, мне нужна ваша помощь

Comment: Либо указывайте полный к pyinstaller, либо в переменных окружения в PATH добавить путь к папке с скриптами, чтобы по названию файла можно было вызвать его

Comment: Добавь к переменным окружения путь к папке где находится PyInstaller, и все будет работать нормально :)

Comment: Я прикрепил еще один скрин, ничего не изменилось

Comment: 1 -  попробуйте перезайти в консоль/перезагрузиться. 2 - покажите что у вас в переменной окружения PATH. 3 - если установлено несколько интерпретаторов Python, попробуйте удалить остальные.

Comment: 2. Вот что в моей переменной окружения PATH:
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Afmin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts

Comment: в конце я добавил путь к pyinstaller

Comment: Сверху я прикрепил изменения после ввода в моей переменной окружения PATH. Но до сих пор нет результата

Answer (score 3):

В Windows 7, pyinstaller устанавливается в другую папку Scripts

Для того, чтобы работала команда pip install, я прописал в PATH следующие строки:

```
C:\Users\Brine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\

C:\Users\Brine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
```

а для того, чтоб из CMD консоли заработала команда pyinstaller, в PATH пришлось добавить третью строку:

```
C:\Users\Brine\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts\
```

Будьте внимательны, посмотрите куда pip install устанавливает pyinstaller и добавьте этот путь в PATH.

Comment: Этот ответ помог, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что максимальная версия питона для работы с PyInstaller это 3.7.0, а у тебя 3.8.0.

> PyInstaller’s main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.5—3.7

Информация с оф.сайта

Answer (score 0):

Поробуйте пересоздать виртуальное окружение и там создать  EXE
Надо создать папку в ней открыть командную строку там python -m venv venv , в рабочей папке появится папка venv, потом
в командной строке venv\scripts\activate,  python -m pip install pyinstaller --user, 
pyinstaller --noupx --onefile --noconsole --path venv\yourfolder  yourprogram.py